# Stored Procedure Oracle SQL to process large queries

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to implement a stored procedure which updates my table (over 10k rows)
but only a certain amount of rows `rownum`

Current procedure:

```
       create or replace PROCEDURE P_UPDATETOANON AS 
BEGIN
         UPDATE PERSONENVERKEHR_VERTRIEBSSYS15.HIST_TEST
         SET TS_RESPONSIBLE = 'test'  
         WHERE TS_RESPONSIBLE != 'test' 
         AND length(TS_RESPONSIBLE) >  3;

END P_UPDATETOANON;

Error(3,10): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(3,48): PL/SQL: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

How do I implement to only update a certain record of data?

Comment: How do you decide whether a row has to be to updated or not? Please post some sample data and desired result

Comment: The motivation of this procedure is to anonymize the users in the column "TS_RESPONSIBLE" and set them to 'test'

Comment: Ok, but it's still unclear what data you need to update; say you have 1000 rows with TS_RESPONSIBLE > 3 AND TS_RESPONSIBLE != 'test', which rows would you update?

Comment: All rows not containing 'test' and length smaller 4 Characters

Answer (score 1):

If you need to update only a given amount of rows, without any logic to decide which ones, you may simply need:

```
UPDATE PERSONENVERKEHR_VERTRIEBSSYS15.HIST_TEST
  SET TS_RESPONSIBLE = 'test'  
WHERE TS_RESPONSIBLE  != 'test'
  AND length(TS_RESPONSIBLE) > 3
  AND rownum < 100 /* for example */
```

It seems even that your user has no rights to update the table; you first need

```
grant update on PERSONENVERKEHR_VERTRIEBSSYS15.HIST_TEST to MQCDBA
```

given by the owner of the table or other granted user.

Comment: How to update only certain records?
(Top 10 / rownum <10?)
I heard I need a subselect for it but dont know how to build it.

Comment: to use rownum, I first have to select the data or I will get weird rownums or am I wrong?

My current stored procedure I editted in my post

Comment: If you want to update some rows, with no logic, rownum is ok. if you want to decide which rows to update, please expain the logic you need. The error you posted is due to the fact that your login user has no right to update the table

Comment: Procedure MQCDBA.P_UPDATETOANON (MQCDBA is owner)
i granted to PERSONENVERKEHR_VERTRIEBSSYS15 execution rights, still not working?

Comment: You need to give grants on the table; just showed an example